# Node.js/Babel 6/Devtool: Source files structure breaks with "babel-register" added

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-devtools, babeljs

I recently started to use the new "[devtool](https://github.com/Jam3/devtool)" module for debugging Node.js in Chrome Dev Tools.

The debugging process was a dream until I tried to use some ES6 code by using `require("babel-core/register");` in the entry point of my application.

I could still use the devtool debugger but everything except my "node_modules" files where dumped into the "no domain" folder.

I assume the es6->es5 compiling needs some sort sourcemap to keep the folder structure possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Way late to this but hope this helps someone, here goes.

From my understanding you're trying to use `es6` features when running projects using the `devtool` command to server projects via Chrome Dev Tools?

To do this follow the babel docs on setting up a new project (make sure you have a `.babelrc`) then server your projects by running

`devtool -r babel-register [MY_FILE_NAME.js]`

Instead of simply `devtool [MY_FILE_NAME.js]`

You don't need to add any imports in your app's entry point if you followed the babel docs correctly.

see https://github.com/Jam3/devtool